# How do I delete "left over" files in a git remote working directory?

Tags: git, deployment, repository

I have a local and a remote git repository that I use for website local development and remote deployment.

Locally, I have deleted several files and committed the change. All is well. When I push the changes to the remote repository, the files that were deleted in the local working directory are still present in the remote working directory.

How do I make the remote working directory reflect the deletions?

Comment: Unable to reproduce through a quick test.  I assume the files were previously tracked and show up as deleted in a `git show` locally, that there were no error messages (the push appeared successful), and that you're using a reasonably current git with the repo's *receive.denyCurrentBranch* set to *updateInstead*; please correct if any of these assumptions is wrong.  What do you see if you run `git status` on the remote?  Is the commit ID (sha1) for the remote's `HEAD` the same as the local's?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thanks for the detailed questions.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Oops, premature enter. My remote server's git is old. Let me get that updated and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the version of git on the remote server was pretty old. Updating it seems to have fixed everything. Thanks to Mark Adelsberger for that clue!